# Hartshorne Chapter 2 exercise 4.8. d)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In this question in Algebraic Geometry by Hartshorne one has to show that the product of two morphisms of Schemes has a property $\mathcal P$, thats true for closed immersions, stable under composition of two morphisms with the property and stable under base extension, but I am not sure what is meant by the product of two morphisms.

Do they mean $f:X \to Y$  and $f':X' \to Y'$ and then the product $f \times f':X \times X' \to Y \times Y' $?

Or do they mean the fibred product $f:X \to Z$ and $g:Y \to Z$ and then $f \times_Z g: X \times_Z Y \to Z$?

At first I assumed the first one, but then I found solutions online with either usage, which confused me, so which is it supposed to be?

Comment: You're more likely to get a reliable answer if you give the full details of the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Y, Y'$ are schemes over a base scheme $S$, and if $f : X \rightarrow Y$ and $g : X' \rightarrow Y'$ both have property $P$, then $f \times g: X \times_S X' \rightarrow Y \times_S Y'$ has property $P$.

Comment: Okay and in the case that we have arbitrary schemes are given we just regard them as $\mathbb Z$-Schmes?

Comment: @linkja yes, as $Spec(\mathbb{Z})$  is the final object in the category of schemes.